# Javascript script does not log to browser console

Tags: javascript

I have a script but I can't figure out why it won't execute correctly.
I've declared all my variable and up to the prompts it works fine, but I can't see why it won't log the results of my functions.

```js
var leasePriceString = prompt("Input lease price per month"); 
var ecoScoreString = prompt("Input eco score");
var catalogValueString = prompt("Input catalog value");
var c02String = prompt("Input C02");        

var leasePrice = parseInt(leasePriceString); 
var ecoScore = parseInt(ecoScoreString);
var catalogValue = parseInt(catalogValueString);
var c02 = parseInt(c02String);        

var brutoMonth = true;
var VAA = true;        

function calculator(){
    function brutoMonthCalc(){
        if (ecoScore >= 74){
            brutoMonth = ((leasePrice*12)/13.92)-75;
            console.log(brutoMonth);
        } else {
            brutoMonth = ((leasePrice*12)/13.92)-150;
            console.log(brutoMonth);
        }
    }
    function VAACalc(){
        VAA =  6/7*catalogValue*(0.055+((c02-105)*0.001));
        console.log(VAA);
    }
    brutoMonthCalc();
    VAACalc();
    console.log("price per month is =" + brutoMonth + VAA);
};        

calculator();
```

Comment: You are never calling your `calculator()` and `VAACAlc()` functions and so your variables aren't getting set. And, even if you did call `calculator()` there is a nested function of `brutoMonthCalc` which would then also need to be called.

Comment: Your `calculator()` function is never called in the code you posted, but even if it were called it would do nothing.

Comment: Not only that, the functions inside `calculator` are never called either. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: "*Did I forget to make it run*" - yes, exactly that.

Comment: Okay. So, i've added some stuff to call it, but it still doesn't work. :-S

Comment: Then please edit your question to show the current code so we can see what's going on now.

Comment: Jeps. Just did it.

Comment: typo: `leaseprice` != `leasePrice`  Please, use the developer tools to check your syntax errors

Comment: Always, always, always work with your developer tools (F12) open to the Console tab when you are having a problem. If you do, you will now see that you have an error.

Comment: @jlanssie You're scoping your variables incorrectly.  you should only have one `var brutoMonth ...` and it should be that first one where you set it to true.  After that, you should be using `brutoMonth = ...`.  Same goes for `VAA`.  You're essentially making new variables every time you use `var `.

Comment: Right. I've corrected that. But still it won't log anything to the console. It doesn't show anything. :-S

Comment: @jlanssie Yes, it does. Look at your developer's console. Hit F12 in your browser and look at the console tab. You have an error and it will show you that.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a lot, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified some aspects of your code, and provided and explanation below:

```js
    var leasePriceString = prompt("Input lease price per month");
    var ecoScoreString = prompt("Input eco score");
    var catalogValueString = prompt("Input catalog value");
    var c02String = prompt("Input C02");
    
    var leasePrice = parseInt(leasePriceString);
    var ecoScore = parseInt(ecoScoreString);
    var catalogValue = parseInt(catalogValueString);
    var c02 = parseInt(c02String);
    
    // Declare global variables here
    var brutoMonth;
    var VAA;

    function calculator(){
        function brutoMonthCalc() {
          if (ecoScore >= 74) {
            brutoMonth = ((leasePrice * 12) / 13.92) - 75;
            console.log(brutoMonth);
          }else{
            brutoMonth = ((leasePrice * 12) / 13.92) - 150;
            console.log(brutoMonth);
          }
       }
    
       function VAACalc() {
         VAA = 6 / 7 * catalogValue * (0.055 + ((c02 - 105) * 0.001));
         console.log(VAA);
       }
     
       // Call functions here
       brutoMonthCalc();
       VAACalc();
  
    }
     
    calculator();  
    console.log("price per month is =" + brutoMonth + VAA);
```

In the above code I mainly changed two things:-

1. **Declaring global variables**: You want to declare your variables only once, and then assign them in the functions that you intend to run to change their value.
2. **Calling Functions:** After you write a function, you need to call it later on. Only when you call it do the expressions in the function run.

Comment: You may have improved some aspects of the code, but it still doesn't run.

Comment: How so? If you click `Run Code Snippet` it seems to be working.

Comment: Now, it does. After your edit. It wasn't before you edited `leasePrice` to correct its capitalization.